# Search showing results but link does not work

Tags: search-results

I have 2010 installed and have configures search and content types. I am getting resuts which look like they are working very well however the link does nothing. It appears as it should, is blue and is a link but clicking it does nothing.

Here is an example of a result:

Letter

Commander Ross Wendt … Dear Commander Wendt, … Please find enclosed the above invoice for development of a web enabled OH&S incident reporting database provided by The Frame Group Pty …
Authors: Brad Ferguson***8195;Date: 11/10/2003***8195;Size: 50KB
file://dev-fp1.dev.local/DevProjects/3series projects/31000 projects/3102000001 mhq web development work/invoice 3102000001-01_5 november 2003.doc

The word Letter is a link to the file but clicking it does nothing. If I copy and paste the link into a browser it find the location/document no problem. Help!!

Comment: What is the URL of Letter? Can you post that information?

Comment: HI there - Its as it appears above 'file://dev-fp1.dev.local/DevProjects/3series projects/31000 projects/3102000001 mhq web development work/invoice 3102000001-01_5 november 2003.doc' Note this does work when pasted directly into another browser.  As I have mentioned in ny respons to the answer below,  If I go onto the server which hosts the SP and hit the page the link works as expected.  Could this be a network thing?  The SP box is on a different domain BUT I can ping from one domain to another...

Comment: That's the FILE protocol. Is the file hosted in a fileshare or on a SharePoint Site? If file is correct, are you certain that browser security is not preventing you from opening the link?

Comment: Yes its a file share.  I have crawled a file share content type hence the file:// I am using IE 8. I believe there no such out of the box restrictions, is this what you are saying?  I think its a cross domain security/network issue which is outside the scope of sharepoint.  Are you aware of a sharepoint setting/ar4ea I could look at?

Comment: On second thoughts it cant be a browser restriction.  If you re-read my initial post it explains the link can be pasted into a new browser and it works as expected by serving the file

Comment: I am not convinced. Is dev-fp1.dev.local a trusted domain for the browser?

Comment: Feel free to correct my understanding of how browsers work and this logic.  The link does work when pasted into the browser therefore IMO it can not be a security/trusted issue.  Also, as I have already explained clicking the link has no action, nothing happens.  A site that is not trusted does not stop the reaction to the click.  Also it will prompt you to the fact its not trusted.  Whats your thoughts on my understanding?

Comment: Anyone else got any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Internet Explorer or some other browser? When you hover over the link with mouse pointer, do you see the link at the bottom of the browser?

Here is a [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/68484/16290) for an answer to a similar question.

> [This](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/sharepoint-search-results-customizations) tutorial is about how to customize search results.
> There are three topics:
>
> - Customization to highlight search keyword
> - Customization to open Search result items in new window
> - Customize People Search result

Comment: HI there. I use IE 8.0, FF and Chrome.  Behavior is the same in all.  Yes I do see the link, as I said in my post 'It appears as it should, is blue and is a link but clicking it does nothing'.  Something to add.  If I go onto the server which hosts the SP and hit the page the link works as expected.

Comment: See the link in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the search site to your local intranet locations in IE. You might also have to add the `file://servername` url to local intranet as well.

Comment: Hi Wade, and welcome to SP.SE! Do you think it is possible for you to add a little more details about how to add a site to a zone in IE, and also why that can help this situation? It would make your answer more helpful