# How can I allow search results to be opened when clicked in Chrome or FF?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, enterprise-search

I have an Enterprise Search Center site collection that crawls/searches from a file share.  It works fine in IE, but when you attempt to click the links from the results in Chrome or FF, nothing happens.  I assume it has something to do with the files being Local.  The URL's generated appear to be the same in Chrome and FF and will work if I copy them and paste them into the address bar.

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work in Chrome and FF?

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding. What do you mean when you say the files are "local?"

Comment: I apologize.  What I meant is that they have the 'file://' prefix which I thought would make it interpreted as local.

Comment: He's trying to point to a file on another server...most likely not an URL

Comment: Where are the files stored?

Comment: The files are stored on a separate server than our sharepoint server(s).

Comment: So they're located on a file share?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my description (sorry...wasn't supposed to sound smart there).

Comment: Sounds exactly like this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68446/open-file-from-file-server-after-finding-it-in-search-results

Comment: Sorry, I apparently didn't read your first sentence. :P

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and FF aren't going to be able to do a lot of OOTB SharePoint features.

For example, you can't use "Open with Explorer" for a document library.

This sounds like another proprietary software issue strikes again.

You can link to an application page that will download the file.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox both should allow you to click on a document and perform some sort of action (in most cases download). Chrome and Firefox are both supported for downloading documents.

Comment: Correct. If it's in http format, which he isn't using.